# Messed up with libudev files and now I can't boot

Tags: boot, permissions, symbolic-link

So I wanted to test cgminer on ubuntu and I was getting an error message about missing libudev file so in a rush I tried to read a few answers on here but instead of fixing it, I just messed up things more.

Now when I restarted my pc I can't even boot into ubuntu.

In recovery mode the error is this:

```
mountall: error while loading shared libraries libudev.so.0 cannot open shared object file : no such file or directory
```

So I returned to console and tried to see history of what I messed up. These are the commands that I used when I messed up things about libudev.

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0

cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -sf libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0

sudo cp libudev.so.0.13.0 libudev.so.1
```

So it looks like I overwrote some functional file or linked to some missing file but I don't know what to do because any thing that I try while i'm in recovery is telling me error that files are locked and it's read-only file no matter if i'm with root or my username.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an old installation of ubuntu and extracted libudev.so.0 file to my installation overwriting a messed up file and it worked on next boot. So i fixed it.